# 'Simplest form' expand brackets?

Tags: factoring, fractions

When a question asks 'write in its simplest form', do I factorise, or expand...? Eg...

$$
\frac{x+10}{(x-4)(x+3)}
$$
Or
$$
\frac{x+10}{x^2-x-12}
$$

Or does it even matter?

Comment: The first is probably "simpler" than the second.  If you intend to integrate then something of the form $\dfrac{a}{x-4}+\dfrac{b}{x+3}$ for constants $a,b$ will be even easier to deal with

Comment: The question is quite literally to write it in its simplest form, I have skipped the subtraction of the fractions, I don't plan to integrate etc...

Comment: If I remember correctly simplify meant make it look as complex as possible by expanding everything

Comment: I would say the second is in the simplest form (though I like the first one more), well at least my professor always said that when you finish canceling you should expand so there are no factors (I didn't agree with her though).

Comment: Alas this is one of the ambiguities of the term "simplest form," which is why on math contests and the like they usually specify what to do in cases like this.  Which of the two forms is "simpler" is wholly dependent on what one is going to do with the answer.  If this is the answer you need to write down for a math exam then it is probably best to clarify with the professor, or write down both, since they're equal anyway.  Of course all of this is moot if you have specific instructions on what "simplest form" means in your case.

Comment: For me ${2 \over x-4}-{1\over x+3}$ is the simplest form, also if you are.not planning to integrate.

Comment: Neither of these expressions is simpler than the other. I would be dismayed if anyone had a strong opinion about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate, possibly useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900917/is-there-any-official-specific-convention-that-defines-whether-an-expression-is/3901091#3901091

Answer (score 0):

Simplify, in this context, and in your exam, means that the terms must be factorised wherever possible, (with any common factors cancelled), so the first form is correct.

Comment: So you find $\frac{1}{3\cdot 2^2}$ simpler than $\frac{1}{12}$?

Comment: @B.Goddard no obviously not, but in the context of **algebraic fractions**, simplified means fully factorised.

Comment: Not to be belligerent, but "Sez who?"  Most folks would consider $x^2-1$ simpler than $(x-1)(x+1)$.  If this is true in polynomials, why isn't it true in the field of polynomial fractions?