# Is there any official, specific convention that defines whether an expression is considered "Simplified"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convention

I see all the time in high school math textbooks problems saying to "simplify" an expression. Their explanations of what it means for an expression to be "simplified" is a bit vague and does not reflect the rigor mathematics usually provides:

"*To simplify an expression means to do all the math possible.*" ([OpenStax Intermediate Algebra](https://openstax.org/books/intermediate-algebra-2e/pages/1-1-use-the-language-of-algebra))

I have encountered numerous situations in which there is ambiguity as to what looks "simpler" to people. For example:
$$
\text{Simplify: }\frac{a^2b^{-3}c}{c^2b}
$$

Some people would say the most "simple" way to write this is $a^2b^{-4}c^{-1}$. However, most textbooks would consider $\frac{a^2}{cb^4}$ to be the "correct" answer.

From my perspective, problems beginning with "Simplify" don't really make sense (and are frankly unfair to the students) unless there is a clear definition of what it means for the expression to be "simplified" (especially with teachers who are picky about that kind of thing).

Is there some sort of convention for simplification that I don't know about that makes this work?

Comment: I doubt it. From what I've observed while in school, "simplest" usually just means "cleanest expression", which is *highly* subjective. Excellent question!

Comment: Both $a^2b^{-4}c^{-1}$ and $\frac{a^2}{cb^4}$ should count as *simplified* and as correct

Comment: rational numbers has a well known simplification step: $\frac{ca}{cb} \Rightarrow \frac{a}{b}$, i.e. cancelling the common multiplier. Finding new multipliers is slightly difficult, but one way is with gcd(a,b) algorithm which makes it: $\frac{a}{b} \Rightarrow \frac{a/gcd(a,b)}{b/gcd(a,b)}$

Comment: @Henry I agree. Unfortunately not all teachers feel this way. I haven’t had that problem, but I’ve heard from other people who have.

Comment: It would be very hard to learn about any proofs that involve algebra without first learning how to "simplify", and I don't really see an alternative.

Comment: @SenZen well, with proofs and other applications of Algebra, it's more about manipulating the expression to meet your purposes, rather than a generic "simplification"

Comment: @Caleb H. How would you learn which manipulations to use to meet your purposes without first learning the generic simplifications?

Comment: @SenZen the same way you learn the generic simplifications - the textbook/teacher generally gives examples of how to use the different rules (i.e. the rule of negative powers) in the context of "simplifying". Why not just teach it in the context of an equation instead, where there is a purpose to the simplification?

Comment: @Caleb H. So you would have your students learning how to find all the values of $x$ that satisfy $11x - 8 = 25$ _before they've even learnt that $33/11 = 3$_ ??

Comment: @SenZen I think you're misunderstanding me. I certainly think the rules for manipulating the expressions (in your case, division) need to be learned before they can be properly used. I just don't like the specific wording "simplify" because it is rather subjective.

Comment: Fair enough, that was a strawman. So the students would be able to prove that $\frac{25+8}{11} = 3$, however they would not recognize $\frac{25+8}{11}$ as something that can be made into a "simpler" object. So their solution to $11x - 8 =25$ would be $x =  \frac{25+8}{11}$. Then either you say, yes that's it or you teach them to simplify! So you haven't changed anything?

Comment: @Caleb H. I also disagree that simplification is highly subjective. Give any mathematician $11x - 8= 25$ and they'll come back with $x=3$. Can you give me an example of an equation where mathematicians would give their answers is different forms?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116074/discussion-between-caleb-h-and-senzen).

Comment: I often told classes "No self-respecting algebra student would leave [such-and-such] in that form" (eg, $(25+8)/11$ for $3$, or $\sqrt{8}$ for $2\sqrt{2}$), sometimes sparking discussions about subjectivity (eg, Do we prefer "$\cos x\csc y$" over "$\frac{\cos x}{\sin y}$"? Maybe; but for making conditions of undefined-ness conspicuous — *Caution: Denominator must be non-zero!* — maybe not. (Also, $\csc y$ may increase cognitive burden.)) ... I'll note that *Mathematica* and I often have *very* different notions of "simplified", particularly with trig. Simplicity is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: "Really what I meant to say is that it is unfair for teachers to mark an answer wrong on a simplification question just because the student’s answer doesn’t exactly match the answer in the textbook. I think we can both agree on that?" - not if the answer is 1/2 and you give 4/8, where day one of fractions is learning how to simplify them. Expressions, sure, IDK (that's where I got off the bus) ... but [not simplifying fractions is inexcusable](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/24568/student-asked-me-if-it-is-necessary-to-simplify-fractions-at-the-end-of-answerin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is right:

> From my perspective, problems beginning with "Simplify" don't really
> make sense (and are frankly unfair to the students) unless there is a
> clear definition of what it means for the expression to be
> "simplified" (especially with teachers who are picky about that kind
> of thing).

In K-12 "simplify" usually means "manipulate so that you end up with an expression of the form we've seen as the answer to similar problems".

That is indeed ambiguous. It does however give students practice with the kinds of manipulations they are supposed to learn how to do. It makes exams easier to grade. How much it helps students learn interesting and important mathematics is doubtful. Good students understand the ambiguity, but still do what the teacher expects. If they have good teachers they can discuss the ambiguity in a way that does not disturb their classmates who just want to get the right answer.

Comment: Right you are. For my money, the only proper use of the word is in the sentence, “Don’t simplify your answer.”

Comment: _"How much it helps students learn interesting and important mathematics is doubtful"_ You're kidding right? Good luck learning anything beyond natural number arithmetic without learning generic simplifications first...

Comment: And as for the "ambiguity is unfair" perspective, well, would you suggest we only teach math with clear precise definitions? Sorry kiddo, I know you haven't learnt addition yet, but the peano axioms come first

Comment: @SenZen You do need to become proficient at algebraic manipulation, just as you need to learn the multiplication tables. But the manipulations, like the tables, are a tool, not an end in themselves.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Everything is tool, and everything is an end in itself, depending on what you're trying to achieve.