# How to simplify $\dfrac{x+2}{x^2-2x-3}+\dfrac{x}{x^2-2x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, fractions

So I was once again bored when I decided to to try and see if I could do maybe some simple Algebra and came up with this problem:$$\text{Simplify: }\dfrac{x+2}{x^2-2x-3}+\dfrac{x}{x^2-2x}$$Which I thought that I would be able to do. Here is my attempt at simplifying the aforementioned equation:$$\dfrac{x+2}{x^2-2x-3}+\dfrac{x}{x^2-2x}$$$$=\dfrac{x+2}{x^2-2x-3}+\dfrac{1}{x-2}$$$$=\dfrac{x+2}{(x+1)(x-3)}+\dfrac{1}{x-2}$$$$=\dfrac{x^2-4}{(x+1)(x-3)(x-2)}+\dfrac{(x+1)(x-3)}{(x+1)(x-3)(x-2)}$$$$=\dfrac{2x^2-2x-7}{x^3-4x^2+4x+6}$$$$\text{Or }\dfrac{(x-2)(x+2)+(x+1)(x-3)}{(x+1)(x-2)(x-3)}$$

---

$$\mathbf{\text{My question}}$$

---

Is the solution that I have achieved correct, or what could I do to attain the correct simplification/attain it more easily?

Comment: It's not clear what "simplify" means. You've done a lot of algebra with rational expressions. Presumably it's correct. (I haven't checked.) See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900917/is-there-any-official-specific-convention-that-defines-whether-an-expression-is/3901091#3901091

Comment: you can use Wolfram to simplify and compare with your result. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify%5B%289x%2B2%29%5E2-2x%5E2%2B3%5D

Comment: Result looks correct, but as Ethan said, it depends on what you mean by simplify... You could use partial fractions decomposition to write this as $\frac{5}{4(x-3)}+\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{4(x+1)}$, that can be considered simpler in some contexts

Comment: Think in terms of reducing a fraction to lower terms. In this case you have a rational expression; the numerator remains in expanded form while the denominator can be-and you did factored it. My answer would be $\frac{2x^2-2x-7}{(x+1)(x-2)(x-3)}$. There are no miraculous ways to simplify as @Sil suggested. That is not simplifying but rewriting in an equivalent way, possibly convenient for the next operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivation is fine, but there is an important issue to note: while the original expression is *not defined* for $x=0$ the second one is a valid expression also when $x=0$, in this sense they are *not completely equivalent*.